# Cannot remove .bak file

Tags: sql-server, backup, java

I have a java application that:

1. Reads a .bak file from a windows fileshare and restores it in SQL Server on a remote windows server
2. Does various modifications on the database restored from the `.bak` file in step 1
3. Backup the resulting database to a temporary .bak file (called `somename.bak_tmp`) on a windows fileshare
4. Renames `somename.bak_tmp` to `somename.bak` (in the same directory on the same windows fileshare)

All the above steps works fine sometimes... I modified the rename code at some point which basically does this:

```
executeSql("master..xp_cmdShell 'rename "+tmpFile+" "+newName+"'");
```

to use the full path as `newName`. As a result the renaming failed. But now I cannot remove the `somename.bak_tmp` from the fileshare. Actually I cannot even see it (only the parent folder that contains it).

I have tried to delete the restored database from SQL Server but I still cannot delete the folder containing `somename.bak_tmp`. I get an `Access Denied` if I try to open it. If I right click the folder it says this on the owner tab:

> *Unable to display current owner.*

And I cannot change the owner to Administrator even though I am logged in as administrator. Any ideas on what have happened to the folder during the failed rename and how to remove it?

Comment: can you try running a command prompt on the machine that hosts the fileshare, by right clicking cmd and saying "run as admin" and trying to rename the file?

Comment: I have tried to open CMD in admin mode and tried to delete the folder: 'rmdir folder /S' but get Access is denied. Samen message with the rename command.

Comment: Can you try this? Right-click on folder -> Properties
Security Tab, Click on Advanced button, Owner tab, Edit..,
select "Administrators" in "Change owner to" and mark the checkbox "replace owner on subcontainers and objects"

Comment: I have tried that and I just get "Access Denied". I have also tried to delete (and close connections) the restored database from the mssql server but I still cannot remove the .bak file. The only way to remove it is to terminate the SQL Server Service which is not an option during regular hours.